# 'Could not validate or distribute application to App Store' in App Submission

Tags: ios-appstore

We have developed an iOS universal application and are trying to upload it to the App Store.

From the Organizer window, when we try to validate or distribute the application, it loads for a long time at the login page and then gives a "request timed out" error. It's happened for the last 10 days.

How can we upload the application to the App Store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Application Loader. When Xcode has trouble connecting, Application Loader seems to work every time for me. Archive your application as an ipa and upload it through Application Loader.